# Can I ensure that Haskell performs atomic IO?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, io, concurrency

I have two threads in haskell that perform IO. (They print only). Something like the following:

```
thread1 :: IO ()
thread1 = putStrLn "One"

thread2 :: IO ()
thread2 = putStrLn "Two"
```

I am currently getting results like the following:

```
OnTwoe
OTnweo
```

How can I ensure that each thread completes its IO atomically?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use a synchronization variable to ensure atomic access to the resource.  A simple way is with an MVar:

```
main = do
   lock <- newMVar ()
   forkIO $ ... lock 
   forkIO $ ... lock
```

Now, to do IO without interleaving, each thread takes the lock:

```
thread1 lock = do
      withMVar lock $ \_ -> putStrLn "foo"

thread2 lock = do
      withMVar lock $ \_ -> putStrLn "bar"
```

An alternate design is to have a dedicated worker thread that does all the `putStrLns`, and you send messages to print out over a Chan.

Comment: As an exercise: try writing this using transactional memory to order access to the resource.

Comment: I will give that a shot!
also I changed:
withMVar lock $ (\_ -> putStrLn "bar")

Comment: I haven't used this design but the alternate design you mention at the end has worked pretty well for me in a couple of projects.

Comment: What if the monad context isn't in IO? I was using the `monad-parallel` package, and it's able to fork monads that aren't IO. I couldn't use `mVars` for the non-IO monads.

Comment: @Toymakerii is correct. the 2nd parameter of `withMVar` should be a function, not just `putStrLn "..."`.