# Why putStrLn end of line is out of thread lock?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, io

When I use `putStrLn txt` from several threads in Haskell, it's possible to get the text intercalated with the end of lines, but if I use `putStr $ txt ++ "\n"` always works.

is it right? What am I doing something wrong?

**Example 1:**

```
thread 1: putStrLn "txt 1"
thread 2: putStrLn "txt 2"
thread 3: putStrLn "txt 3"
thread 4: putStrLn "txt 4"
thread 5: putStrLn "txt 5"
```

Example of output:

```
txt 1txt 3
txt 2txt 5txt 4
```

**Example 2:**

```
thread 1: putStr $ "txt 1" ++ "\n"
thread 2: putStr $ "txt 2" ++ "\n"
thread 3: putStr $ "txt 3" ++ "\n"
thread 4: putStr $ "txt 4" ++ "\n"
thread 5: putStr $ "txt 5" ++ "\n"
```

Always output one line for thread:

```
txt 1
txt 3
txt 2
txt 5
txt 4
```

Thanks

**Update:**
I'm using `ghc 6.12.3` and `base-4.2.0.2`

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you describe on GHC 7.0.3 - I'm using forkIO and tried both threaded and non-threaded runtimes. Also, looking at the GHC implementation at http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-IO-Handle-Text.html there seems to be no real difference on how the two cases are handled.

Comment: @Antti: Seems it was changed in `base 4.3.1.0`. In `base 4.3.0.0` and earlier [it's defined as](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.0.0/doc/html/src/System-IO.html) `putStrLn s = do putStr s; putChar '\n'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Haskell doesn't provide any thread safety guarantees on `putStr`, `putStrLn` and friends, so it would also be allowed to interleave character-by-character, even when doing the concatenation up front like you do.

See [Can I ensure that Haskell performs atomic IO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981984/can-i-ensure-that-haskell-performs-atomic-io) for an example of how to synchronize your I/O properly.

Comment: Thanks, I have been thinking that the lock was used inside putStrLn.

Answer (score 3):

With the definition from base 4.3.0.0 (`putStrLn s = do putStr s; putChar '\n'` - thanks hammar) I would assume that `putStr` locks the `stdout` handle and is therefore able to output the string without intercalation. That would explain why the output intercalates when using `putStrLn`: the lock is released after `putStr` and another thread acquires the lock before `putChar`. I'm only speculating, though.

In any case, updating GHC and with it the base library to 4.3.1.0 should fix the problem.